# Get all photos belonging to a user_id

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have two tables, one `user_info`:

```
table user_info {
    user_id ;
    fname;
    laname;
    contactno;
    address;
}
```

And `photos`:

```
photos {
    photo_id;
    user_id        (foreign key);
    photo_name;
    caption;
}
```

Please tell me how I can use an `INNER JOIN` query in PHP/MySQL, when e.g `user_id = 11` click on photos and then query will join the table for resultant `user_id`.

Comment: Not yet another social networking site :C

Comment: `select * from table_a a inner join table_b b on a.user_id = b.user_id where a.user_id=1`  @JamWaffles - I hope it is called GooglePlusPlus.

Comment: Don't worry @JamWaffles, this network is apparently inside PHP/MySQL.

Comment: With *very little* effort you could find out yourself...

Comment: I suggest a MySQL / PHP tutorial after your previous question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365986/am-creating-social-networking-website-but-tell-me-about-facebook-like-wall-pos and make sure you pay extra attention to the SQL Injection section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM user_info u
JOIN photos p USING (user_id)
```

Where `<fields>` is the list of field names you require

Comment: No problem, unless you were being sarcastic? It _was_ a pretty simple edit, and I'm easily confused.

Comment: @JamWaffles no sarcasm ... just me having an off moment ! was just going to edit it and noticed you had already changed it ! Thanks

Comment: Ah I see. Well, glad I could be of service :-)

Comment: @MuhammadSameerAli I'm not going to tell you anything. You need to work this out for yourself; it's a simple problem that's easy to solve. Perhaps you should learn to write PHP/MySQL properly before attempting a project such as a SN site? Also, on a personal note, please don't write another one - Facebook is bad enough.

Comment: IIRC, you have to use `USING( user_id )` or mysql will throw a fit.

Comment: @tereško you are indeed fully correct ! updated ... thanks